# How to know which instance of Visual Studio to kill?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

I have several instances of Visual Studio open and they show up as devenv.exe in the Task Manager. I need to kill one of them. How do I know which is which? Using Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Task Manager, if you go to the applications tab, you can right click on the instance you want to kill based on the name, then click on "Go to process". It should select the process you want to kill.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) instead of Task Manager.

It allows you, among other things, to inspect all open handles within a particular process and/or to search for DLLs and handles - either of these tools should help you identify a specific instance, if say you're looking for a particular instance that has one specific file opened.

Comment: This is a way more general solution that works well for a shared system. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from sysinternals. From the Properties dialog (Job tab), you'll know which one to kill.

Answer (score 1):

Download Process Explorer and drag the Cross-air over your stucking window.
http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653

Answer (score 0):

Detach one tab in one instance of Visual Studio to new window. This instance will get (2) next to it's name in task manager. I think it's quickest way to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is:

- Delete `bin and obj` folders in the project source (some debug bin items will remain skip them)
- Clear remaining files in bin (the ones that remain are the running processes)
- Go to the task manager processes and search for the names of the remaining items to delete then end each proccess
- you can now clear all bin files and rebuild